# Sequence. Finding the terms from given equations

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of three terms is $33$, and their product is $1287$. Find these terms. I tried to solve this, I went to a result but I'm not sure I was right.The given equations are:
                                $$a_1+a_2+a_3=33$$
                                $$a_1a_2a_3=1287$$

since $a_2=a_1+d$ and $a_3=a_1+2d$ I found that $a_1=11-d$. I replaced $a_1$ to the second equation and I'm getting:        $$(11-d)(11-d)+d(11-d)+2d=1287$$ Now i'm not sure how to continue because since I should multiply first I get some strange results, if I eliminate $d$ from $(11-d)+d$ I get to something but I don't know if I'm allowed to sum first here because product usually comes first.

Comment: You will have to improve the question to make it understandable, since you don't introduce $d$ anywhere. Also, from what you wrote it seems that you are dealing with an arithmetic progression, but you don't say it anywhere.

Comment: In your notation, we should  end up with $(11-d)(11)(11+d)=1287$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some mistake when you plugged in your results from the first equation into the second equation.

From the first equation we have $a_1=11-d$. We can use this to rewrite $a_2$ and $a_3$: $a_2=a_1+d=11-d+d=11$, and $a_3=a_1+2d=11-d+2d=11+d$. Now we plug this into the third equation:
$$1287=(11-d)(11)(11+d)$$
Dividing both sides by $11$, we get

$$117=(11-d)(11+d)=121-d^2$$
Hence $d^2=4$, and so $d=\pm2$. Now, we don't know for sure what the difference $d$ is - whether it is $-2$ or $2$, but it turns out it doesn't matter. If it is $-2$ then we get $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(13,11,9)$, and if it is $2$ then we get $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(9,11,13)$, and in both cases we get the same three numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to decompose 1287 in prime factors.

$$1287 = 3^2\times 11\times 13$$

So the obvious solution here is $9+11+13=33$

Note that if the sum was 49, the answer would be $3+3\times11+13=49$